# nested dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

For the following nested dictionary I would like to sum  values for each `'ab'`, `'bc'`, `'cd'`, `'de'` keys respectively. Basically, collapse the dictionary.  Preferably, using comprehension with `=sum` but cannot figure out the proper syntax:

```
{'hot': {'111': {'ab': 1, 'bc': 3, 'cd': 5, 'de': 7}}}
{'hot': {'111': {'ab': 12.5, 'bc': -31, 'cd': 2.5, 'de': 13}}}
{'hot': {'111': {'ab': 10, 'bc': 3, 'cd': 0, 'de': -2}}}

{'hot': {'110': {'ab': -1, 'bc': 0, 'cd': 1, 'de': 1}}}
{'hot': {'110': {'ab': 8, 'bc': 20, 'cd': 41, 'de': 13}}}
{'hot': {'110': {'ab': 1.75, 'bc': 2.3, 'cd': 6, 'de': 0}}}

{'hot': {'109': {'ab': 2.7, 'bc': 24, 'cd': 4, 'de': 5}}}
{'hot': {'109': {'ab': 41, 'bc': 6, 'cd': 12, 'de': 33}}}
{'hot': {'109': {'ab': 32, 'bc': 7, 'cd': 18, 'de': 3.75}}}

{'cold': {'111': {'ab': 25, 'bc': 2, 'cd': 3, 'de': 2.1}}}
{'cold': {'111': {'ab': 5, 'bc': 8, 'cd': 5, 'de': 17}}}
{'cold': {'111': {'ab': -71, 'bc': 42, 'cd': 5, 'de': 16}}}

{'cold': {'110': {'ab': 23, 'bc': 2.4, 'cd': 2.1, 'de': 4.3}}}
{'cold': {'110': {'ab': 11, 'bc': 2.8, 'cd': 4.5, 'de': 2.4}}}
{'cold': {'110': {'ab': 4, 'bc': 5.7, 'cd': 8.7, 'de': 1}}}
```

Desired output:

```
dict['hot']['111'][AB] = 1 + 12.5 + 10 = 23.5
dict['hot']['111'][BC] = 3 - 31 + 3 = - 25
```

etc

Comment: You want all of the 'ab' to be in one sum, or you want to sum all of the 'ab' corresponding to each respective key path in the dictionary(like in your desired output)?

Comment: It's not clear what your input is.  Are you saying you've got multiple dicts with similar keys, and you want to sum the values grouped by key?

Comment: That is not a proper data structure.

Comment: What would your input be?

Comment: Are these dictionaries contained in a list?

Comment: By the way, how is the data stored? Did you need a file reader?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your data is in a list, because with this, you get the answers you expect.

```
data = [{'hot': {'111': {'ab': 1, 'bc': 3, 'cd': 5, 'de': 7}}},
{'hot': {'111': {'ab': 12.5, 'bc': -31, 'cd': 2.5, 'de': 13}}},
{'hot': {'111': {'ab': 10, 'bc': 3, 'cd': 0, 'de': -2}}},

{'hot': {'110': {'ab': -1, 'bc': 0, 'cd': 1, 'de': 1}}},
{'hot': {'110': {'ab': 8, 'bc': 20, 'cd': 41, 'de': 13}}},
{'hot': {'110': {'ab': 1.75, 'bc': 2.3, 'cd': 6, 'de': 0}}},

{'hot': {'109': {'ab': 2.7, 'bc': 24, 'cd': 4, 'de': 5}}},
{'hot': {'109': {'ab': 41, 'bc': 6, 'cd': 12, 'de': 33}}},
{'hot': {'109': {'ab': 32, 'bc': 7, 'cd': 18, 'de': 3.75}}},

{'cold': {'111': {'ab': 25, 'bc': 2, 'cd': 3, 'de': 2.1}}},
{'cold': {'111': {'ab': 5, 'bc': 8, 'cd': 5, 'de': 17}}},
{'cold': {'111': {'ab': -71, 'bc': 42, 'cd': 5, 'de': 16}}},

{'cold': {'110': {'ab': 23, 'bc': 2.4, 'cd': 2.1, 'de': 4.3}}},
{'cold': {'110': {'ab': 11, 'bc': 2.8, 'cd': 4.5, 'de': 2.4}}},
{'cold': {'110': {'ab': 4, 'bc': 5.7, 'cd': 8.7, 'de': 1}}}  ]
```

And the code is this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))

for d in data:                   # for the list
    for k1 in d:                 # for the hot-cold level
        for k2 in d[k1]:         # for the 1[0-9]{2} level
            for k3 in d[k1][k2]: # for the [a-z]{2} level
                counts[k1][k2][k3] += d[k1][k2][k3]

print(counts['hot']['111']['ab'])
print(counts['hot']['111']['bc'])
```

There are 2 levels of defaultdict nesting.

Output:

```
23.5
-25
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use imports for this. The guy is clearly new to this type of thing in Python, and it's mainly about organizing the data. Your example has too many loops, extra overhead.

Comment: You need one loop per depth of nesting. That's just the nature of OP's data.

Comment: @spikespaz well, you could just use machine code, then you don't even have to use Python!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, I get it. It's Python, it's slow no matter what. But even if it is a slow language, there's no reason to make it work even slower, is there?

Comment: @spikespaz what? No. My point was that saying "You shouldn't have to use imports for this" is bad advice. The best advice you can give to someone new to programming is "don't reinvent the wheel."

Comment: @spikespaz I think you're missing the point here. There's two points actually. But I think the more important thing to note here is that you should not be here to bash other answers, just because you think your solution is better. Leave that for the reader to decide.

Comment: @Coldspeed I wasn't bashing, I was criticizing, and that's not a bad thing. There's nothing wrong with your answer, and mine isn't better, We were answering for two different things we thought the OP meant. Sorry if I gave you the wrong impression.

Comment: I can accept criticism if it's constructive. This doesn't make sense to me. Can you give me a solution that _does not have_ 4 loops, **if you want the sum of all combinations**? If not, why are we even having this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**This example is making a "getter" function. It *might* reduce a little overhead compared to parsing the whole dict list at once.**

The double dictionary iteration here can be reduced by simply parsing the accepted dictionaries within the first iteration, however it is separated into `accepted` with a second iterator for demonstration purposes.

Here is a complete code example which prints out the desired result, `23.5`.
First, create a list of the dictionaries you want to read from:

```
dictionaries = [
    {'hot': {'111': {'ab': 1, 'bc': 3, 'cd': 5, 'de': 7}}},
    {'hot': {'111': {'ab': 12.5, 'bc': -31, 'cd': 2.5, 'de': 13}}},
    {'hot': {'111': {'ab': 10, 'bc': 3, 'cd': 0, 'de': -2}}},

    {'hot': {'110': {'ab': -1, 'bc': 0, 'cd': 1, 'de': 1}}},
    {'hot': {'110': {'ab': 8, 'bc': 20, 'cd': 41, 'de': 13}}},
    {'hot': {'110': {'ab': 1.75, 'bc': 2.3, 'cd': 6, 'de': 0}}},

    {'hot': {'109': {'ab': 2.7, 'bc': 24, 'cd': 4, 'de': 5}}},
    {'hot': {'109': {'ab': 41, 'bc': 6, 'cd': 12, 'de': 33}}},
    {'hot': {'109': {'ab': 32, 'bc': 7, 'cd': 18, 'de': 3.75}}},

    {'cold': {'111': {'ab': 25, 'bc': 2, 'cd': 3, 'de': 2.1}}},
    {'cold': {'111': {'ab': 5, 'bc': 8, 'cd': 5, 'de': 17}}},
    {'cold': {'111': {'ab': -71, 'bc': 42, 'cd': 5, 'de': 16}}},

    {'cold': {'110': {'ab': 23, 'bc': 2.4, 'cd': 2.1, 'de': 4.3}}},
    {'cold': {'110': {'ab': 11, 'bc': 2.8, 'cd': 4.5, 'de': 2.4}}},
    {'cold': {'110': {'ab': 4, 'bc': 5.7, 'cd': 8.7, 'de': 1}}}
]
```

Next, make your function.

```
def get_sum(temp, num, pt):
    accepted = [] # Initialize a list of accepted dictionaries that fit the arguments passed.
    pt_sum = 0 # Initialize the variable for the sum of your parts, starting at 0.

    for dictionary in dictionaries: # Iterate through the dictionary list.
        if temp in dictionary and num in dictionary[temp]: # Check if the dict on current iteration has what you want.
            accepted.append(dictionary[temp][num]) # It does, so add it to accepted.
            # Let's pause here. Say you are reading the first dict in the list. So that means, this is what the fuction is working with:
            # {'hot': {'111': {'ab': 1, 'bc': 3, 'cd': 5, 'de': 7}}}
            # Now with the append function, we are calling "dictionary[temp][num]".
            # We know that each of these keys exist, because we just checked it.
            # So this eliminates the need to add the whole dictionary to "accepted".
            # Basically, we are cutting out the last section, because that's what we need. So you end up with:
            # "{'ab': 1, 'bc': 3, 'cd': 5, 'de': 7}" in the list "accepted".

    for dictionary in accepted: # Now go through the ones that have the data you need.
        pt_sum += dictionary[pt] # And simply add the value to the sum.

    return pt_sum # Return the part sum.
```

And now you can use it:

```
print(get_sum("hot", "111", "ab"))

>>> 23.5
```

**The simplified code that I mentioned at the top would be this:**

```
def get_sum(temp, num, pt):
    pt_sum = 0

    for dictionary in dictionaries:
        if temp in dictionary and num in dictionary[temp]:
            pt_sum += dictionary[temp][num][pt]

    return pt_sum
```

Essentially just adding to `pt_sum` in the first loop, so there is *no* second iteration, which was never required.

Comment: It's not like you've removed the loops at all. It's just that you're fetching the sum for a single combination. Now try fetching them all.

Comment: @Coldspeed That wasn't the question. From the way he said he wants to use it, `dict['hot']['111'][AB]` looks like  fetching values based on that he already knows. I have him a function that does that. It's basically the same thing, except with parenthesis, quotations, and commas instead of square brackets.

Comment: Sorry, the data comes from ElementTree for loop, reading from parsed xml. I just did not want to overburden the question. Basically trying to store parts of xml into a nested dictionary, perform some calculations and and save as new xml.

Comment: @Vrun Could I see the output from the parser in a pastebin or something?